# Is it possible to create a view with one specific value pair of each table in a schema?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake schema with 100+ tables. Each has a column „load_time“. Is it possible to create a view with each of the table names and their highest value for load_time (latest/newest load_time)?

I don’t really know if I should use Joins or Unions or anything because I have so many tables…

Comment: If `load_time` is the timestamp when the table is last updated, I think you can have a look at column `LAST_ALTERED` in the [`TABLES view`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables). It shows the timestamp the table was last altered.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following statement and generate the DDL for the views, pass the schema  and column name to the SQL.

```
-- untested
    select 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AS SELECT TABLE_NAME, MAX(' ||
COLUMN_NAME || ')' || ' FROM ' || TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.'|| TABLE_NAME || ' GROUP BY ' COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE '*' and column_name = '';
```